# list array of objects using python flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, mongodb-query, mongoalchemy

i have a payload as shown below which is stored in mongodb

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5865fbf5558b670ac091c81e"), 
    "sensors" : [
        {
            "sensorStatus" : "green ", 
            "sensorName" : "s1"
        }, 
        {
            "sensorStatus" : "red ", 
            "sensorName" : "s2"
        }
    ], 
    "camera" : [
        {
            "cameraName" : "cam1", 
            "cameraStatus" : "live"
        }, 
        {
            "cameraName" : "cam2", 
            "cameraStatus" : "live"
        }
    ], 
    "checkpoints" : [
        {
            "checkPointName" : "chk1"
        }
    ]
}
```

trying to write route to display this data as shown below

```
@gateway_bp.route('/gateway',methods=['GET'])
def list_gateWay():
    gateways = Gateway.query.all()
    print gateways
    return Response(json.dumps(gateways),  mimetype='application/json')
```

i am getting the error has

```
TypeError: <app.model.canvasmodel.Gateway object at 0x02E99D10> is not JSON serializable
```

the schema is as shown below

```
from app.dbconfig.extensions import db

class Sensors(db.Document):
    sensorName = db.StringField()
    sensorStatus = db.StringField()


class Camera(db.Document):
    cameraName = db.StringField()
    cameraStatus = db.StringField()

class Checkpoints(db.Document):
    checkPointName = db.StringField()

class Gateway(db.Document):
    sensors = db.ListField(db.DocumentField(Sensors), db_field='sensors')
    camera = db.ListField(db.DocumentField(Camera), db_field='camera')
    checkpoints = db.ListField(db.DocumentField(Checkpoints), db_field='checkpoints')
```

please help to correct the get request thanks

Comment: Where is the output of `print gateways`? Can you also `print type(gateways)`?

Comment: print gateways [<app.model.canvasmodel.Gateway object at 0x03766CD0>, <app.model.canvasmodel.Ga
teway object at 0x03766BB0>, <app.model.canvasmodel.Gateway object at 0x03766BF0
>]

Comment: print type(gateways) <type:'list>

Comment: So it's a list of `Gateway` Objects. `json.dumps()` wont work on lists. It will take a JSON object as an argument.

Comment: please guide how to convert the list as objects but sensors in sampel is array of object not sure how do it please modify the query

Comment: Can you try this: `json.dumps(gateways[0])` and see if it prints valid json.

Comment: no same error i am getting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132065/discussion-between-mygz-and-dhana-lakshmi).

Comment: I think `_id` causing problem here. Try adding `_id` filed in `Gateway` class